# how can i add image and text in a UIButton programmatically(objective c)

Tags: objective-c

i want to add a button having both image and text, text below the image. can anyone guide me.I am adding button programmatically in UIScrollview. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically set image and text on UIButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887959/programmatically-set-image-and-text-on-uibutton)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below represents one way to create a `UIButton` programmatically in Objective C.

```
UIButton *mButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[mButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickedMe:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[mButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[mButton setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
mButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[yourScrollView addSubview:mButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using Interface Builder**, there is a very easy way to do this:

1. Select the button and set a title and an image. Note that if you set the background instead of the image then the image will be resized if it is smaller than the button.[image: IB basic image and title]
2. Set the position of both items by changing the edge and insets. You could even control the alignment of both in the Control section.

[image: IB position set]
[image: IB Control set]

Example :
[image: Button preview]

OR

You could even use the same approach by code, without creating UILabels and UIImages inside as other solutions proposed.

OR

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```